# How to use both destination_prefix_naming and default_file_naming in Apache Beam WriteToFiles?

Tags: apache-beam

I have an Apache Beam pipeline that is writing to files via:

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
    my_pipeline = (
        p 
        | "ReadTable" >> beam.io.Read(source) 
        | "WriteSomeFiles" >>  beam.io.fileio.WriteToFiles(
            path="/path/prefix/to/directory/",
            destination=lambda record: record["filename"],
            file_naming=beam.io.fileio.destination_prefix_naming(),
            sink=JsonSink())
        )
```

This successfully names the files with the "filename" entry in my record. How can I also set the suffix of the file? E.g. with `default_file_naming` like:

```
default_file_naming(prefix="my-prefix", suffix=".json")
```

Comment: No, but I'm not sure how it's relevant. Accepted answer is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`destination_prefix_naming` takes an optional parameter `suffix` that you can pass to set the suffix of the file.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way you learned this other than this documentation? https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.22.0/apache_beam.io.fileio.html?highlight=destination_prefix_naming  ... Very new to Apache Beam and indeed sort of new to python.

Comment: I looked at the source of this function: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.35.0/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/fileio.py#L431 (Not sure why it's not showing up in the documentation too...)

Comment: Got it. Thanks! That is the ultimate source of truth :)